# TextView text is not displayed

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using Relative Layout to display ImageView and TextView. But default text assigned to TextView is not displayed, please check below Xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/trainName"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:background="#F81A07"
            android:textColor="#1BADEE"
            android:text="Default Text"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:padding="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Alex, did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Within your inner `RelativeLayout` you have the attribute `android:layout_height="100dp"` which will make the `RelativeLayout` have a height of 100dp.

Within the `TextView` that resides inside that view, you have the attribute `android:padding="100dp"` which will add 100dp padding on all sides of the `TextView` which pushes it just outside the borders of the `RelativeLayout`.

Try adjusting the height of the inner `RelativeLayout` *or* reducing the padding of the TextView.

Answer (score 0):

You should be remove 
`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true`" is TextView

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and yes you have set wrong attribute android:padding="100dp".

Here is your code:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/trainName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#F81A07"
            android:text="Default Text"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#1BADEE"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />
```

I am agree with The Fluffy Robot's answer.

Happy Coading !!

Answer (score 0):

I have try your xml code . there is one minor problem **android:padding="100dp"**

remove it from text view . please sure about that layout height and child view padding are should not same.

this is my xml code try this:

**with padding**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">


<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/trainName"
android:text="Default Text"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:background="#F81A07"
android:textColor="#1BADEE"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:padding="40dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Without padding**

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#ffffff">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trainName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#F81A07"
        android:text="Default Text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#1BADEE"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope its work for you

Answer (score 0):

Ya, The fluffy Robot's point is correct,
Check it and change it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/trainName"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:background="#F81A07"
            android:textColor="#1BADEE"
            android:text="Default Text"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```